# Adding Legend Label for Hline ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a legend to ggplot2 based on some horizontal comparison lines that were added in. My code currently looks like this

```
aplot <- ggplot(aData, aes(x = DEP, y = DECAY, color = GENDER))        
aplot + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = meanCD, color = "purple")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = medianCD, color = "forestgreen") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = medianSAD, color = "goldenrod3", linetype = "dashed")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = meanSAD, color = "deeppink", linetype = "dashed")
```

meanCD, medianCD, meanSD, medianSD are all stored as seperate values and I need to add them to the graph for comparitive purposes. aData is just a bunch of points. I cannot get a legend to show up giving the color of the line and giving an appropriate label and I am unsure how to accomplish this in ggplot2.

Comment: You should probably put them all in one variable and pass the values to `yintercept` in `aes`. You could also put `color` or `linetype` in `aes` to add a legend for your current code, but it won't be as clean